# Memory Leak issue. How to "read" the root paths?

Tags: .net, memory-leaks

I have a memory profiler and trace an application.
In that application when I open consecutively a form multiple times (6), the application became unstable and may close.

A memory leack was suspected. So, I trace the following root path
[image]

How to read this graph in order to fix the memorey leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root is on top and your control/class is on the bottom. Usually you read in either direction trying to find the problem in the path. As mentioned before, EventHandlers are a very common problem. Especially in a static context. Meaning, some class hooks by += onto an event and never unhooks again. That's no problem as long as both components, the class and the event providing one, are non-static and not kept anywhere else.

In your example, the UserPreferenceChanged event seems to be the problem and I guess it's a static event. So, the UltraToolbarsManager (which seems to be static too), hooks up that event. It seems that the UltraToolbarsManager also handles all click events for toolbar icons. So, the problem is, that your class hooks up to a ToolClick event.

Possible solutions are

1. try to dispose/clean-up the UltraToolbarsManager (if non-static) so
   that the UserPreferenceChanged event is unhooked or
2. unhook from ToolClick event when cleaning up your own class.

Comment: The toolClick event was the cause, thank you. I removed this custom event and used directly the control's event.

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of eventHandlers at the top of your stack.

A common cause for memory leaks are instances is directly rooted by an EventHandler. Your 'leaked' instance might only be used as the target of an EventHandler and there is no other way anymore to reach it. They might even already be disposed.

I would recommend to use (the trail) of the [.NET MemoryProfiler](http://memprofiler.com/). It can capture snapshots and automatically point out some common problems like eventHandlers keeping instances alive.

Comment: Right, initially you just wrote `I see a lot of eventHandlers at the top of your stack. Might eventHandlers keep instances alive?` which seems a comment but now it's better

Comment: Thanks. As you can see this IS a snapshot, I just only want to understand what actions to do, or how to "read" the problem )

Comment: @serhio I understand it IS a snapshot. however does it provide you with the required details to identify eventHandlers causing leaks?  All information that is provided in the question is a stack.